# Printing at a specific location using Java

Tags: java, printing

I am developing a application which basically prints data on a cheque. The data is obtained from a database and the Java application (or an applet) has to print the data (name, amount, date etc) at appropriate positions on the cheque.

How can I print at a specific location on a paper using Java?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your specific programming question?

Comment: My specific question is:  How to print at specific location on a paper using Java?

Answer (score 1):

[Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) can do it. How? search the web, there are a lot of tutorials.

Comment: Who can we print without Jasper Reports? Giving x and y positions ?

Answer (score 0):

yep.. Jasper is good and you can use iReport for drag and drop report creation in the jasper format.